# how to get alias of the caller in windows 8 app

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

I am creating a windows 8 app (xaml) in vs 2012. I need to extract the caller alias and pass the information to Database.

Would really appreciate if you provide any pointer.

I tried to use:

```
var loggedInUserAlias = await Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.GetPrincipalNameAsync();
var loggedInUserAlias1 = await Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.GetDisplayNameAsync();
```

but no luck. I have logged into my machine using Administrator account. I should get as <>\Administrator as alias.

Comment: Please be more specific what you mean by "no luck." Did the code throw an exception? Did it return an empty string? What happened?

Comment: GetPrincipalNameAsync() method is returning empty string And GetDisplayNameAsync() method is returning only "Administrator" whereas I need <<MachineName>>\Administrator